# The colors of the layers of my first 2D animation are wrong for some reason

Tags: animation, add-on, render-layers, layers, vertex-colors

I've just created my first 2D animation and I used separate layers and the "voxel heat diffuse" addon that you can find [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/voxel-heat-diffuse-skinning?ref=2).

With it I've been able to make the 2d animation faster. But,anyway,there is a little problem and I don't know if it's caused by the addon. I rendered the first frame and I saw that some layer have odd colors. Can someone suggest to me where could be the mistake ?

This is the first rendered frame of the animation :

[image: 1]

and this is how it appears on the 3D view :

[image: 2]

You can find the blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauN2YyU2I4VnRGS28/). Thanks.

Comment: Voted the anwer up as this is quite specific issue (sorry that I cannot help you directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of "Mingfen Wang",that's "Just click the 'Diffuse BSDF' item, and select 'IAP_SHADELESS' shade, then render".